# How to find last opened EXCEL.EXE opening time?

Tags: vb.net

Lets say your computer is running more than one EXCEL.EXE on task manager.

How to find last opened EXCEL.EXE opening time?

Following code is not okey because for each loop doesnt follow EXCEL.EXE opening order!

```
   For Each prog As Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
        Label1.Text = prog.StartTime.ToString
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a LINQ query to find the last/most recently opened Excel instance:

```
Dim latest = (
    From p In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
    Order By p.StartTime Descending
).FirstOrDefault()
If latest IsNot Nothing Then
    Label1.Text = latest.StartTime.ToString()
End If
```

You could remove the `Descending` to get the first/earliest opened instance.

Not as efficient as looping, since it has to sort the processes.  [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/) has a `MaxBy` method that would be better:

```
Dim latest = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL") _
    .MaxBy(Function(p) p.StartTime)
```

Comment: @Kramer Have you added a MoreLINQ reference through NuGet? You will also need to `Import MoreLinq`. Otherwise, the first example is standard LINQ stuff.

Comment: Your first code is already working properly. Do you think I should add that reference and prefer to use second code?

Comment: @Kramer I would probably use the first example, unless I needed MoreLINQ for something else. I also just realized you would want `MaxBy` and not `MinBy` anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this to get the oldest running instance.

```
  Dim oldestStartTime as DateTime = DateTime.Now
  Dim oldestProg as Process

 For Each prog As Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
  If prog.StartTime < oldestStartTime Then
    oldestStartTime = prog.StartTime
    oldestProg = prog
  End If

 Next
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "more professional" code. Can you elaborate on what you think that actually means to you?